# Greenplum Database -Problem of Count Distinct Queries Slowness

Tags: greenplum

We are using Greenplum OSS version for Data Warehouse and having multi terabyte data available in same.

We have peculiar problem that Count(distinct) queries doesn't perform, and Execution plan is prepared by Postgres Query Optimizer rather than GPORCA

Below are the details on Problem.
Can anyone help on same

**Background on Infra:-**
a.  Cluster of 8 Data Nodes
b.  16 vcpu on each Node
c.  32 GB RAM on each node
d.  8 Segments Per Node
e.  Cluster IOPS – Read - ~4 GB/s

**Background on Data:-**

1. Fully Distributed Table of 120 Million record – on 64 Segments
2. Each Segment contains – 2million record

**Background on Requirement & Problem Faced:-**

1. 20+ Independent attributes to be probed for distinct values for Dynamic Time Inputs.
   ( Important Point to note -> These attributes are independent in nature, so cannot combine them together via group by clauses, and distinct is required)
2. Count(distinct) - We need within 10 sec interactive query response to process these counts for Dashboard. ( But Getting 180+ sec response time)

**Our Analysis:-**

1. As per Explain plan , GPORCA is not even invoked for these queries and Postgres query optimizer is preparing Execution plan
2. We tried to create Append-Optimized, Row/Columnar tables, to try bumping response time, but no improvements visible as such.
3. Switched Off – ‘optimizer_force_multistage_agg’ – No effects yielded.- Response time - 192 sec
4. Switched Off – ‘enable_groupagg’ - No effects yielded - Response time - 192 sec
5. Switched On – ‘enable_hashagg’ – Response time - 120 sec

**Based on above facts, we want to know**

1. Why the GPORCA optimizer not getting enabled
2. Why count(distinct) queries taking 15X more time than count(*) queries. Is parallelization not being utilized.
3. How we can optimize these queries.
4. Is there any other alternative to meet this requirement.

Answer (score -1):

A couple of observations:

- just to confirm, ORCA is turned on database wide (optimizer=on)?
- 8 segments with 16 vCPU is a 2:1 ratio of cpu to segments.  VMmware generally recommends 3-4 cpu per segment
- 32 GB RAM seems a little small to me for that many segments per host.

Questions:

- have you run analyze or analyzedb (not sure if that is in open source version) on the table to ensure stats are fully up to date?
- are you doing select distinct on 1 of the 20 attributes or is it a combination of multiple attributes you are running select distinct on?  If the first, have indexes been built on the most used column?
- have you tried explain analyze on the query so you can see exactly where things are getting held up?
- how many columns in this table?

Jim McCann
VMware Tanzu Data